# Text flow interupted by absolute positioned element

Tags: css

I am trying to build a chat box and position arrive time inside the message div
by positioning it as absolute and placing it relative to parent but it is overlapping with chat content.How to position arrived time span so it does not overlap with the message and stay at respective positions

### html

```
<div class="chat-box">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label data-expanded="Close Chatbox" data-collapsed="Open Chatbox"></label>
  <div class="chat-box-content">
    <div class="msgWrapper">
      <div class="msgwrapperleft">
        <div class="icon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/40X40"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="Message">Message from Client
          <span class="ArrivedTime">1 minute ago</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="msgWrapper">
      <div class="msgwrapperleft">
        <div class="icon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/40X40"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="Message">Message from Client
          <span class="ArrivedTime">1 minute ago</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msgWrapper">
      <div class="msgwrapperleft">

        <div class="Message">Message from Client
          <span class="ArrivedTime">1 minute ago</span>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/40X40"></img>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

### css

```
body {
    height:3000px
}
.chat-box {
    font:normal normal 11px/1.4 Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    color:#333;
    width:300px;
    /* Chatbox width */
    border:1px solid #344150;
    border-bottom:none;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:9999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-top-left-radius:4px;

}
.chat-box > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:block;
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:26px;
    z-index:4;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
}
.chat-box > label {
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/244tirb.jpg) -100% 0 #24201a;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0 1em 1px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
}
.chat-box > label:before {
    content:attr(data-collapsed)
}
.chat-box .chat-box-content {
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
/* hover state */
 .chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:hover + label {
    background-color:#404D5A
}
/* checked state */
 .chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-color:#212A35
}
.chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content:attr(data-expanded)
}
.chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .chat-box-content {
    display:block
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
}
left {
    float: left;
}
span.left:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8.5px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid white;
}
span.left:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid black;
}
span.right:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #dbedfe;
}
span.right:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid black;
}
span.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dbedfe;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width:96%;
    margin:1%;
}
.msgWrapper {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
  position:relative;
    margin:0 0 2px  0;

}
.msgwrapperleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;

}
.iconright {
    float:left;
    width:18%;
    margin:1%;
}
.iconleft {
    float:right;
    width:18%;
    margin:1%;
}
 .iconleft img {
    border-radius:40px;
}
.iconright img {
    border-radius:40px;
}
.MessageRight {
  float:left;
    width:74%;
    padding:2%;
    margin:1%;


}
.MessageLeft {
  float:left;
    width:74%;
    padding:2%;
    margin:1%;

  text-align:right;

}
.Time {
    width:100%;
}
 .ArrivedTimeRight {

    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px;
    right:2px;

     font-size:7px;
}
.ArrivedTimeleft
{

    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:2px;

     font-size:7px;
}
.chat-box:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    top: -14px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/244tirb.jpg) -100% 0 #24201a;
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
```

}

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tfyzao9j/2/)

Comment: Yes, absolute positioning is out of the flow. There's the real and correct behaviour. What do you need? Change to relative? Explain what you want

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/tfyzao9j/6/

I changed the time stamps to `position: relative;` and set their position to to `bottom: 0;` and `left: 0;` or `right: 0;` respectively.

Comment: I used another approach Instead of absolute I placed span inside the p which inline element by default and put text-align property to align right and also I found solution with absolute element itself for it the container have to be set as relative then child elements can be set using absolute anyway +1 for thinking in the way I thought.And finally what I settled for https://jsfiddle.net/tfyzao9j/4/